# Posso marcar um checkbox por botão?

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

Preciso acionar uma `<checkbox>` por um botão. Pode ser por meio de JavaScript ou PHP, algo que faça com que o valor único da `<checkbox>` seja selecionado.

Quero isso porque pretendo escondê-la e só acioná-la por um `<button>`.

```html
<td><?php echo utf8_encode($dados['ped_valid_proposta']);?>&nbsp;dias</td>
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></td>
<td>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="my_checkbox" name="os_codigo1" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($dados['ped_codigo'])?>">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Selecionar</label>
  </div>
</td>
```

No caso esse `<checkbox>` está dentro de uma estrutura de repetição que pode selecionar consulta por consulta, mas quero que clicando no botão da "lupa" eu consiga acionar o `<checkbox>` correspondente.

Comment: Se a checkbox vai ficar escondida, como vc vai saber que ela foi acionada?

Comment: Vc quer que seja submetido apenas 1 checkbox ou pode ser vários que foram acionados?

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa. Se é uma estrutura de repetição vão ter vários checkbox na tela ao mesmo tempo pelo que me parece. Além disso, eu reparei que vc tá tem no seu código uma Label, porem o for="" dela está para um ID que não existe, pois o input:checkbox que está ali encima tem um ID com nome diferente do relacionado a Label...

Comment: @hugocsl Realmente mt confuso. Mas acredito que ele deseja remover o label, já que quer que o checkbox seja acionado pelo botão

Comment: Perdão pela demora sendo eu o mais interessado na resposta. Eu já fiz um estrutura de repetição que cria vários checkbox e quando eu seleciono determinando campo da tabela(Isso tudo está dentro de uma tabela) eu envio por $_SESSION[''] e a checkbox serve para diferenciar os vários insert que o campo 'código' possui. Eu tenho um botão com ícone de "lupa" e ele submete a checkbox, porém assim como ela existem vários desses botões para cada linha de insert. Eu gostaria que o botão acionasse a checkbox que ficaria com <pre>display: none;</pre> ou outra forma de escondê-lo.
Perdão pela confusão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, você terá uma tabela com várias linhas, sendo que cada linha terá um checkbox, com o mesmo `name`, que será checado ao clicar no botão da mesma linha.

Neste caso você deve usar o tipo apropriado pra isso, ou seja, o `radio` e não `checkbox`. Um conjunto de `type="radio"` com o mesmo `name` só permite que 1 deles seja checado.

Neste caso você não precisará do `label`, já que o radio será checado via botão. Outra coisa que se torna inútil é o `id="my_checkbox"`, que você pode converter em `class` e esconder o radio via CSS:

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input my_checkbox" name="os_codigo1" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($dados['ped_codigo'])?>">
```

**CSS:**

```
.my_checkbox{
   display: none;
}
```

Também é necessário colocar o `type` dos botões como `button` e não como `submit`:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                                        ↑
```

Via JavaScript você consegue checar o radio da mesma linha do botão com:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // seleciona todos os botões
   var botoes = document.querySelectorAll("td button.btn[type=button]");
   // faz um laço percorrendo os botões adicionando um evento de click
   for(var x=0; x<botoes.length; x++){
      botoes[x].onclick = function(){
         // busca o respectivo radio na mesma linha e checa ele
         this.closest("tr").querySelector("[type=radio]").checked = true;
      }
   }
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var botoes = document.querySelectorAll("td button.btn[type=button]");
   for(var x=0; x<botoes.length; x++){
      botoes[x].onclick = function(){
         this.closest("tr").querySelector("[type=radio]").checked = true;
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.my_checkbox{
   /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
Deixei os radios visíveis apenas como exemplo para visualização:
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>2&nbsp;dias</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input my_checkbox" name="os_codigo1" value="2">
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3&nbsp;dias</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></td>
      <td>
         <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input my_checkbox" name="os_codigo1" value="3">
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela paciência, muitas dúvidas foram sanadas, porém no caso do Label ele não tem uma função na lógica e é mais para o usuário. No mais, muito grato.

Comment: De nada. Como é novo por aqui, saiba como agradecer [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Abs!